# How to add background image to MaterialCardView correctly

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

This is initial effect.Just as show ,the `cornerFamily` of MaterialCardView is `cut`.It's so beautiful.

[image: This is initial effect]

---

I set the background by

```
binding.root.background = resource
```

I want to add background to MaterialCardview .So I tried it.

But the result is like:

[image: This is error effect]

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Please note that my `cornerfamily (cut)` is covered.

---

I also tried it by add background to the chidView of MaterialView

```
binding.root.constraintLayout= resource
```

the result is like:

[image: This is also error result.]

---

How can I make my background image not cover my `cut`?

---

This is my layout code:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_common"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_common"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_common"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_common"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_elevation_small"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_guide"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            imageUrl='@{"https://song.gushiwen.cn/authorImg/"+data.pic+".jpg"}'
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_guide"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_common"
            android:text="@{data.nameStr}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
            tools:text="examle text" />



        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_medium"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
            style="@style/article_Widget.PoemContentBody"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_common"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
            tools:text="examle text" />



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/start_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/end_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/top_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

---

In order to solve the above problems, I compromise. I add a `shapeableimageview` as a child view of the `MaterialCardView`, but there is another bug.

Now, my layout is

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_common"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_elevation_small"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
        imageUrl='@{"https://song.gushiwen.cn/authorImg/"+data.pic+".jpg"}'
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/top_guide"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            imageUrl='@{"https://song.gushiwen.cn/authorImg/"+data.pic+".jpg"}'
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_guide"
            android:text="@{data.nameStr}"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
            tools:text="asdasd" />



        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_medium"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
            style="@style/article_Widget.PoemContentBody"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_common"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/end_guide"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guide"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon"
            tools:text="asd" />




        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/start_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/end_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/top_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/bottom_guide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

I use Theme to set `ShapeableImageView`,if I set  `cornerFamily` to `rounded`,it  will achieve what I expect.

like:[image: what I expect]

---

But when I set  `cornerFamily` to `cut`, it won't achieve what I expect....

just like:[image: error expect]

Then I see the log, I found like:

If I set `cornerFamily` to `rounded`, the log is:

```
The width of MaterialCardView is:984 The height of MaterialCardView is：1617
The width of ShapeableImageView is：984 The height of ShapeableImageView is：1617
```

If I set `cornerFamily` to `cut`, the log is:

```
The width of MaterialCardView is:984 The height of MaterialCardView is：1749
The width of ShapeableImageView is：936 The height of ShapeableImageView is：1701
```

I found that all the numbers were reduced by 48.

what happen?  I set the theme of `cornerFamily`   in MainActivity,it will work in MaterialCardView or any Material Design View like MaterialButton. But why it won't work on `ShapeableImageView` when I set `cornetFamly` to `cut`?

Comment: How are you setting the background currently please share some code

Comment: Ok,I finished it

Comment: Try adding an id to the child of the card view (the `ConstraintLayout`) and then set the background to that instead: `binding.constraintlayout.background = resource`

Comment: I tried it already. It also failure. I show it on my question now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ShapeableImageView`.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
      ...
      app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/cutCorners"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/...." />
```

With the shapeAppearanceOverlay attribute you can apply a custom shape, in this case rounded corners:

```
  <style name="cutCorners" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">xxdp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: In my layout, `AppCompatImageView ` is just a small icon in the upper left corner.My core problem is how to set the background for my root layout material cardview

Comment: @pnkj put the `ShapeableImageView` inside the `ConstraintLayout` to fill the space

Comment: Yes, adding a shapeableimageview can really solve this problem, but it may not be elegant enough? What I think is that maybe material cardview itself has this function, but we didn't find it?

Comment: @pnkj the `MaterialCardView` manages its own background drawable with a `MaterialShapeDrawable`. Overriding this background features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded/cut corners are ignored.

Comment: If I  want the `shapeableimageview ` to fill the `MaterialCardView `,what should I do?

Comment: @pnkj Use `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` in your card